# Nmap indicates that "telepathstart" and "telepathattack" are listening on ports 5010 and 5011 of my Linux box. What are these?

Tags: malware

I have a linux box on my network which, according to Nmap, contains two services called `telepathstart` and `telepathattack` listening on ports 5010 and 5011.

From the same box, I am receiving inbound requests to my computer on port 113, which my firewall is blocking.

[This page](http://www.siterecon.com/Trojan-Port-List.aspx) lists both of these services listening on these ports as Solo and OOTLT, is this accurate? Should I be concerned?

The name of `telepathattack` is what gave me cause for concern, has anybody heard of this? What does it do?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like some sort of psionic warfare tool to me.

Comment: I don't play Starcraft, at least not at work!

Comment: Certainly didn't help with the googling while researching my answer! :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The references on that page are explaining that Solo is known to use TCP port 5010, which is officially reserved for the TelepathStart protocol, and ditto for TCP 5011. If you look thru that list you'll see that lots of malware uses ports that are reserved for other services.

TelepathStart and TelepathAttack are properly listed with IANA as using those ports, so I would expect them to be benign. Let's investigate what runs on those ports. IANA [writes](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.txt):

- Ports: 5010 / 5011
- Service names: telelpathstart / telelpathattack
- Descriptions: TelepathStart / TelepathAttack
- Assignee: Helmuth Breitenfellner

I suppose the contact's email address was hbreitenf@[vnet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_VNET).ibm.com at the time.

A Google search for [[ helmuth breitenfellner telepath ]](http://www.google.com/search?q=helmuth+breitenfellner+telepath) leads us to discover that Helmuth Breitenfellner ported the code of the messaging platform (TelePath) of IBM FlowMark (a [workflow-management system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workflow#Workflow_management_system)) to AIX RS6000.

Sandy Kemsley [writes](http://www.column2.com/2005/04/ibm-tops-aim-market-but-what-of-bpm/) that FlowMark was later rebranded as MQSeries Workflow, and is now [WebSphere MQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_WebSphere_MQ) Workflow.

Is your box running WebSphere MQ Workflow?

If not, then here are three thoughts:

- Today is a good day to run some malware scans.
- You might want to poke at nmap's options a little, and see how much confidence it's service detection has about what's listening on those ports. Maybe use `--version-intensity 9`, for example.
- You could also try the old sysadmin trick of blocking it, and seeing what breaks.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer (and from what I can see the only answer regarding this on the entire web). The aforementioned Linux box is a 3rd party piece of kit to do with out phone system, we contacted the Vendor and they don't seem concerned, I tried the Nmap arguments you suggested (still a newbie when it comes to nmap) and got the same results, we regularly run Malware scans and everything seems ok and we have firewalls rolled out across the network which whitelist activity we like and block the rest so obviously some genius has managed to outsmart us all and we are all doomed!

Comment: I had another thought: you could sniff the traffic (if any) using that port and see if it contains anything useful.

Comment: Just to clarify: Nmap justs sees that ports 5010 and 5011 are open - and finds the names telepathstart and telepathattack for these ports in the services database. The page you reference is only a static listing of ports known to be used by specific programs. It's trivial to change most servers to run on different ports - it might be a web serer, telnet server, anything. Use 'netstat -nap' on the box to find what program is actually using these ports.

Comment: Good point symcbean, I was assuming that JMK was using nmap service version detection (the -sV option) which tries to confirm what is actually listening on the port.

Comment: Nice research on the edit, Jason. This potentially explains what's happening: the server could very well be running WebSphere.

Answer (score 3):

NMAP might not be correct in the guessing of what service is running. I've seen it mistaken several times.

I would check the following things:

Run the following command to check the process of the listening ports.

```
netstat -tulpn
```

Here is an example output:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7337          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      863/postgres    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1670/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 ::1:7337                :::*                    LISTEN      863/postgres    
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1670/sshd       
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           551/dhclient3
```

Here you can see that port 863 is postgres and 1670 is sshd.

I would also run these commands just to make sure:

```
lsof -i #Also lists listening programs 
nmap -sV <host ip> #nmap version detection
grep 5010 /etc/services #linux's port to service name mapping
```

Here is example output when I grepped for port 22

```
ssh     22/tcp              # SSH Remote Login Protocol
ssh     22/udp
imap3       220/tcp             # Interactive Mail Access
imap3       220/udp             # Protocol v3
xmpp-client 5222/tcp    jabber-client   # Jabber Client Connection
xmpp-client 5222/udp    jabber-client
bpjava-msvc 13722/tcp           # BP Java MSVC Protocol
bpjava-msvc 13722/udp
wnn6        22273/tcp           # wnn6
wnn6        22273/udp
xtell       4224/tcp            # xtell server
```

Answer (score 3):

It's impossible for us to tell what program it is without looking at your computer. To do this yourself, run this:

```
sudo netstat -ntpl | grep -e ":5010" -e ":5011"
```

The program you're looking for will be listed as the far-right field in the output.

<sup>*Security note: never just blindly type in a command you read on the Internet. As always make sure you understand it first.*</sup>

Comment: For completeness, note that Windows also has the ability to show you netstat stuff.  The way I normally do it is run the netstat command (netstat -ano) and look for the ports (in the 2nd column local addresses; 0.0.0.0:5011 would indicate port 5011 on all interfaces); the corresponding value in the far right column is the process id.  If you bring up task manager, go the the processes tab, click view->select columns, you can add PID as a column.  You will probably also want to hit the show processes from all users.  You should then be able to determine what process is listening on that port.